# Writing to file format not matching what I type?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a script that iterates through all csvs and does something, then rewrites the file like so:

`reformat_cases_FILENAME_.csv`

Using

`data.to_csv('reformat_cases_{0}_.csv'.format(filename), index=False)`

earlier, that worked, and made the file correctly. I must have changed something, but I don't seem to see what's wrong. Now, running what seems to be correct:

`data.to_csv('reformat_cases_{0}_.csv'.format(filename), index=False)`

I get

`reformat_cases_FILENAME.csv_`

as you can see, the underscore is AFTER the csv, though clearly in the code its before?

**Reproducible example**

create csv with

`+---+---+---+
| a | b | c | 
+---+---+---+
| 1 | 4 | 7 |
+---+---+---+
| 2 | 5 | 8 |
+---+---+---+
| 3 | 6 | 9 |
+---+---+---+`

`import pandas
filename='test.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter = ',')
data.to_csv('reformat_cases_{0}_.csv'.format(filename), index=False)`

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is working fine. Your original filename is 'test.csv', consequently the filename of your new file is 'reformat_cases_test.csv_.csv

If you are using Windows you may not see the suffix (and maybe you have changed the view settings of Windows explorer). At least this happened on my system. But the suffix is still there.

I suggest to get rid of the suffix using Path():

```
import pandas
from pathlib import Path

filename = Path('test.csv')
data = pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter = ',')
data.to_csv('reformat_cases_{0}_.csv'.format(filename.stem), index=False)
```

Also, if you are using Python 3.6+ make use of f-strings, changing the last line to:

```
data.to_csv(f'reformat_cases_{filename.stem}_.csv', index=False)
```